# JBoss AS 7 modules: can do a module with all libraries in a directory?

Tags: jboss, classpath, jboss7.x

I want to define a module with a resource-root like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mymodule">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="libs"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies />
</module>
```

The directory contains all the libraries I need.
I've tried it and it not work, but if I put it this way it work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mymodule">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="libs/lib1.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="libs/lib2.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="libs/lib3.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="libs/lib4.jar"/>
    ........
  </resources>
  <dependencies />
</module>
```

Is there a way to do it the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and use libs.* in your first implementation

UPDATE:

This feature is not currently available, though its under R&D

If you need to include multiple jars in a module, you will need to instantiate each indivisually

Comment: @jonagr brother, i was curious myself did some searching. I dont think there is a way to do that.  try using libs/*.jar. if it doesnt work. i dont see a way . probably it is not meant to work this way

Answer (score 0):

I know this one is old, but I just had the same problem on EAP-7 and solved it as follows:

You may want to create the module using the JBoss CLI. My problem was to supply multiple resources as it was yours. I am using the attribute resource-delimiter and provide my list of resources as follows:

```
module add --name=my.module --resource-delimiter=, --resources=libA.jar,libB.jar,libC.jar --dependencies=my.dep.a,my.dep.b
```

This generates the following module.xml in the respective JBoss folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="my.module">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="libA.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="libB.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="libC.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="my.dep.a"/>
        <module name="my.dep.b"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Hope it helps.